# Python pandas 'ffill' method not working

Tags: python, pandas

In the book 'Python for Data Analysis' there is an example using pandas' Series data structure for reindexing. I copied this simple code into an iPython notebook and run it but it does not change `obj3`.

```
obj3 = Series(['blue', 'purple', 'yellow'], index=[0, 2, 4])
print(obj3)
obj3.reindex(range(6), method='ffill')
print(obj3)
```

In the book it says the output should be:

```
Out[85]:
0 blue
1 blue
2 purple
3 purple
4 yellow
5 yellow
```

Tried a different (supposedly equivalent) method called 'pad' without success. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need assign `obj3 =`:

```
obj3 = obj3.reindex(range(6), method='ffill')
print(obj3)
0      blue
1      blue
2    purple
3    purple
4    yellow
5    yellow
dtype: object
```